# Ceiling fan light dims up and down continuously

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I have a 13 year old hunter ceiling fan with a remote that dims the lights and turns them on and off. The fan works fine but the light just started to dim up and down continuously on its own. Anyone else have a similar issue. How’d you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

#### Remote Problem

Take the battery out of the remote and see if the problem goes away. If it does, try a fresh battery. If the problem comes back then you can try cleaning the contacts under the buttons or get a new remote.